# Json to store settings in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

could someone maybe tell me if its a common practise to use json (arrays) in a database to store settings or preferences. Are there any pitfalls perhaps?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this with MySQL, because MySQL doesn't have native support for JSON. You will run into problems of all sorts, because it's very difficult to retrieve a certain setting or change it. It's a violation of the first normal form of relational databases.

Comment: Yes this is quite common, Wordpress does it for example. But like above you cant natively select single settings or update them in MySQL, but what's best to do is make a Settings class that handles it all.

Comment: @benpix, I will not use the settings to query, it will just be used by php to set up some stuff. So i think i'll just give it a go after I have read everything you guys shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store JSON in MySQL (or any other database) using a `varchar()` field for the serialized format.

When you do so, you lose the flexibility of storing data in a table, because the database does not understand the different "columns" in the JSON object.  You can get the preferences for a single user relatively easily by retrieving the record for the user and parsing the JSON (presumably at the application level).  However, it becomes much harder to efficiently ask questions such as "How many users have option a".

Some databases have native support for JSON (such as Postgres since version 9.2).  In MySQL, you can get libraries of functions that have similar functionality ([here](https://blogs.oracle.com/svetasmirnova/entry/mysql_and_postgresql_json_functions) is an arbitrary example).

If you have just a handful of known preferences that will not change, then create a table with a column for each one.  If you have many preferences and users may only have a subset, then these can be stored with one row per preference.  Such a `UserPreferences` table would have columns for:

- User id
- Preference name
- Preference value

This is a type of entity-attribute-value (EAV) data store.  This has the flexibility of being able to easily add new preferences.  The database can also take advantage of indexes and other techniques for improved performance.  However, this structure is not as flexible as JSON.

Comment: Thanks, the amount of options will be unknown. Usually around 1-15 options. But that differs per user. That's why I was looking for something other than adding extra collumns that other users not use. Also the options are user defined. It can be anything and they are not necesarily shared with with other users. It is meant for a ticket system where one can for instance make a Vip ticket, while others make a Gold, platinum etc ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON based database like MongoDB, then it is

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine ORM 2 in PHP also allows storing json in DB:

> json_array: Type that maps a SQL CLOB to a PHP array using
>   json_encode() and json_decode()

Ref: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html

So it's perfectly OK if you need it!

Answer (score -1):

The question may be better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

That being said, from my experience it's common to store json in a nosql database.  For a sql database you'd want to declare the column to be varchar with a fixed size.  You can make it very large to accommodate large json (what happens when you have a small json string).  You could alternatively make the field smaller (what happens when you have a large json string).  You can see how this would be bad for storing arbitrary json.  If your json isn't arbitrary then you should create specific fields in your table.

Also think about how you would query against your data if it's a json string.

Comment: Thanks alot for sharing thelink and the help!